# Google map SDK version 1.5 integrate with iOS 7 application

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios7

when google map SDK version 1.5 integrate with iOS 7. I got this error.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/apps/Desktop/Map/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/apps/Desktop/Map/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSCameraPosition", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MapViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSMapView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MapViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSMarker", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MapViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSServices", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MapAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't know how solve the problem,can anyone know help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Check with this link it's work for me.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35174534/5872894

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key part of the error is the bit that says: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64.

I am guessing you are building for the arm64bit and the Google Maps SDK doesnt have a 64 bit version.

Try building for armv7, armv7s only

Comment: when i build for armv7,armv7s only, it shows other error.            No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=i386).

Comment: This answer is a little outdated with regard to the 64 bit support. Google released 64 bit support for iOS - http://9to5mac.com/2013/11/19/google-maps-sdk-for-ios-adds-64-bit-support-and-more/